# Удаление Ruby c Windows

Tags: ruby

Как правильно удалить Ruby, чтоб файлы не остались и корректно работала командная строка и т.д

UPD: Win 7 Ultimate 32x. Ставил rubyinstaller с официального сайта

Comment: укажи что за система, и как ставил ruby

Comment: Какая ОС? Как ставил (рубиинсталлер или что?)
И еще, не раби - руби

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В операционной системе Windows необходимо удалить папку и почистить переменные окружения в «Свойства системы → Переменные среды...», удалите все что связанно с Ruby.